# Clustering of users in a dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering

I have a dataset of book reviews:

```
| user_id | ISBN | vote | votes_for_user | average_user_vote | ISBN_categ |
   213      3242X   4.5        12                  3.4             1 
   563      1245X   3.2        74                  2.3             2
```

where

```
  vote = rating given by user to a certain book
  votes_for_user = number of votes the user has in the dataset (nr of rows)
  average_user_vote = average of a user's votes
  ISBN_categ = integer categorical of the ISBN (since that is a string).
```

I want to apply a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN to see how many clusters I can form with this dataset.

My **question** is: 
Should I apply the clustering on the dataframe as it is (minus the ISBN column) or should I construct more features for every user and construct a dataframe where every user appears only once, together with their features, and cluster that?

Remember, the intent here is to cluster users (by user_id), not data points (votes).

Comment: I think you answered your own question already. Running DBSCAN as is will cluster rows (votes) instead of users. Engineer your data so that each user is a row and the columns are features for that user, then do your clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to find clusters of users, then you are interested in finding groups of "similar" reviewers.

Therefore you should:

1. Retain information which relates to the users in a meaningful way - e.g. `votes_for_user`.
2. Discard information which has no meaningful relationship to a user - e.g. `user_id` (unless perhaps it contains some information such as time / order).
3. Be mindful of fields which may contain implicit relationships involving a user - e.g. `vote` may be a result of the interaction between `user` and `ISBN`.